# Spring 5 Reporting

Tags: java, spring, reporting

On the changelog for Spring Framework 5, it states that they removed the compatibility for JasperReports. What reporting tool can I use, that will be compatible with Spring FW 5?

Comment: Can you specify more requirements (eg pdf output, open-source / free) otherwise it is hard to suggest anything?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13294
From the ticket

> **we rather recommend native use of the JasperReports API in Spring MVC
>   handler methods, generating reports from specifically designed RESTful
>   endpoints.** We are dropping our now semi-useless JasperReports view
>   class hierarchy as of Spring Framework 5.0. Note that our existing
>   support against the deprecated JRExporter API remains around in the
>   Spring Framework 4.3.x line until 2019, in particular for existing
>   applications. However, even with 4.3, native use of the JasperReports
>   API is worth considering.

You should use JasperReport but avoid using JRExporter. So just manually add all the JasperReport libraries and create reports when you need them. The Jasper Report generation code could be called by your own endpoints.