# JasperReportsPdfView cannot be resolve in my spring boot.

Tags: java, spring-boot, jasper-reports

In my spring boot I want to generate a list in pdf. According to the tutorial and blog I did everything as the described. But In my controller class when I declare `JasperReportsPdfView view = new JasperReportsPdfView();` I am getting red alert. I don't get any suggestion from intellij idea to import class. 
My controller class is

```
@Controller
public class PdfController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    StudentService studentService;

    @GetMapping("/getreport")
    public ModelAndView getReport()
    {
        JasperReportsPdfView view = new JasperReportsPdfView();
        view.setUrl("classpath:/reports/report.jrxml");
        view.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);

        Map<String, Object> studentMap = new HashMap<>();
        studentMap.put("datalist", studentService.generateReports());
        return new ModelAndView(view, studentMap);
    }
}
```

And my pom.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.avijit</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>test</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Please anyone help me to solve this problem.

Comment: `I am getting red alert.` - Did you try to compile code? What error did you get?

Comment: @AlexK I cannot compile because of this error

Comment: Did you try to build project with maven from command line (not via IDE)?

Comment: No , I didn't. How can I do that ?

Comment: JasperReportsPdfView is not working in 2.0.4 release.

Comment: getting a compile error, class not found, does not look like it is in spring-webmvc version 5.0.5, not sure where it went...

Answer (score 3):

It seems that JasperReports support was removed in Spring 5. See this answer:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47271098/spring-5-reporting
```